# Why do my browser's contents disappear each time I leave the page

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, stock-browser

So for example, I am looking at a web page on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, and the phone rings.  After I am done with the call, I go back to the browser app.  I even go through the menu view where you see a mini version of the rendered web page.

But when I click on it all I get is an empty page...

Do any of yall have ideas?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: On my GNex this only happened when the phone ran out of memory and closed the inactive browser window. But the page would automatically reload after starting it again. Does it reload on your phone?